# No module named '_tf2'

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS kinetic and catkin_make works fine. Then several nodes start but two don't start. Error message:

File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf2_py/**init**.py", line 37, in 
from _tf2 import *
ImportError: No module named '_tf2'

When I check the environment then I have there also /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Question is what I have to do to make it running? There is no module called '_tf2' that I could install.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271974/no-module-named-%27_tf2%27/) by [AlexS](https://answers.ros.org/users/32109/alexs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`_tf2` is a compiled output of tf2_py which is the python wrapper of the core tf2 libray. You should make sure that tf2_py is either installed or built in your workspace and the installation directories are sourced.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosF110](https://answers.ros.org/users/32239/rosf110/) on 2017-10-13**:
Hi, how can I check the tf2_py was properly installed/built/sourced? Thanks a lot!
I was following the steps shown at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf, but at
roslaunch turtle_tf turtle_tf_demo.launch
I get only one turtle shown and ImportError: No module named '_tf2'.

**Comment by [azerila](https://answers.ros.org/users/52921/azerila/) on 2020-07-02**:
I have the same problem, but in my case once it is imported with no problem and once imedietly it gives the import error. I have described it here: https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines/issues/920

I'd be glad if anyone had any clue what I could try